# [__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector when insertin new nsmanegedobject to an to-many relation

Tags: core-data, unrecognized-selector

I am adding a new instance of a Chore object to an Account instance. They are both NSManagedObjects, the relation from Account to Chore is a "one to many" relation.

The account instance is valid during run time as I am able to insert other object to it that follow the same rule for relation as chore does (1 to many), and chore is also valid as in the debugger both the account object and newChore have valid memory addres. The only thing is in the error the addres given, as 0x6d85cb0 is not the same as the address for newChore and account where at the time of this error report. 0x06b74a70 for newChore and 0x06d49700 for account, so I do not know to what 0x6d85cb0 is referring to.

This is the line of code “[account addChoresObject:newChore];” that generates the following error.

this is the line of code [account addChoresObject:newChore]; generates the folowing error. 
2012-05-31 10:19:05.440 Allocation[61436:fb03] -[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d85cb0
2012-05-31 10:19:05.441 Allocation[61436:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d85cb0'

this is the code for the methode where the error is generated.

```
-(void)addChore:(Chore *)newChore
{
    [account addChoresObject:newChore];
    NSError *error;
    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Adding chore" 
                                                        message:@"program not able to add new chore to account" 
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

this is the interface for the Account class, as generated by xcode:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Chore, Gift, Goal, Operation;

@interface Account : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * balance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * birthday;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * photo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *chores;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *gifts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *goals;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *operations;
@end

@interface Account (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addChoresObject:(Chore *)value;
- (void)removeChoresObject:(Chore *)value;
- (void)addChores:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeChores:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addGiftsObject:(Gift *)value;
- (void)removeGiftsObject:(Gift *)value;
- (void)addGifts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGifts:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addGoalsObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)removeGoalsObject:(Goal *)value;
- (void)addGoals:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeGoals:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addOperationsObject:(Operation *)value;
- (void)removeOperationsObject:(Operation *)value;
- (void)addOperations:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeOperations:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

and the Chore class is:

```
@interface Chore : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * interval;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * reward;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Account *account;

@end
```

To me it looks as if the selector is sent to at the wrong address. 
I tryed to use Clean to rid of potential bad build files. 
I have had a hard time before this to get the files generated correctly, as the generated files where called with the name of the app instead of being called with the name of the class and also had problem with some source files that would crash xcode when trying to auto generate iboutlets and ibaction. I am wondering if any one else as had problem with xcode and if re-installing it may fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that the variable `account` in your `addChore:` method is not in the state you expect.

`NSLog` the `account` variable before adding the chore and see what is there. Maybe it is undefined and you have to make sure it refers to what you intend.

Comment: this is what came out of the nslog.  <br/>                              <code>2012-06-01 00:45:31.588 Allocation[76515:fb03] Account: <Account: 0x6dc43f0> (entity: Account; id: 0x6be0670 <x-coredata://DB0B9D45-3C8F-4E47-B2D5-8295C9DA2EDA/Account/p2> ; data: {
    balance = 22;
    birthday = "2012-06-01 04:45:08 +0000";
    chores = nil;
    gifts =     (
    );
    name = TestAccount;
    operations =     (
        "0x6be0840 <x-coredata://DB0B9D45-3C8F-4E47-B2D5-8295C9DA2EDA/Operation/p4>"
    );
    photo = nil;
})<code/>  <br/>

Comment: -- chore come as nil, like the photo who is a 1 to 1 relation. So I changed the addchoresobject to a account.chore = newChore; this actualy works. So this pointed me to take a guess and rename the model file to some thing like modelfile.old, create a new 1 and copy my entety to the new 1 and to delete the app from the simulator to get a fresh start. and it did the trick. so yes this was not a code problem or runtime problem seams my model file was corrupted. as just reinstalling the app got me that the storecoordinator was null. Thanks a gain.